# Styling form method and child elements in one container

Tags: html

I am trying to have my form element on the top of the container then my child elements right beneath it (new line) but couldn't make it.

Please, any idea on how to do that?

Update:

I just update my snippet for a better and clearer idea of what I am looking for. So, again, I just need to have the submit form (file import) buttons on top and other child elements buttons right below.

```css
form {
   display: flex;
   top: 0px;
   margin:0px;  
   width: 1900px;
   padding: 0px;
   align-items: center;

}

  .container {
   display: flex;
   top: 5px;
   margin:20px;  
   border-width: 2px;
   border-bottom-color:#3300ff;
   border-bottom-style: solid;
   width: 1900px;
   border: 5px solid green;
   border-radius: .5em;
   padding: 5px;
   align-items: center;
  }

  .child
  {
  margin-bottom:50px;

  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form action="getfile2" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
     <font size="10"><pre  class="tab"> Import  File:    </pre></font>
     <input type="file" name="file">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

    <div class="child">
      <div id="slider9" class='slider row1 col1'></div>

      <div class="my_text"><center>
      <p>param_1</p>
      <button class="sliderStateChange">Enable</button>
      <button id="turn_off_button9">TURN OFF</button>
      </center></div>
</div> 
    <div class="child">
      <div id="slider10" class='slider row6 col2'></div>

      <div class="my_text"><center>
      <p>param_2</p>
      <button class="sliderStateChange">Enable</button>
      <button id="turn_off_button10">TURN OFF</button>
      </center></div>
</div>

    <div class="child">
      <div id="slider11" class='slider row1 col3'></div>

      <div class="my_text"><center>
      <p>param_3</p>
      <button class="sliderStateChange">Enable</button>
      <button id="turn_off_button11">TURN OFF</button>
      </center></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: any css to this html? if not what exactly are you trying to do? It isn`t really clear...

Comment: @DigitalJedi , I have sliders widgets and import/submit file buttons, what I am trying to do here is just put my sliders under the the submit button of the form element, I mean to have two separate rows here.

Comment: if I inspect your code snippet i can clearly see both your child elements below your form element. They are just empty. Soooo... without your css styling we will not be able to solve or even guess what you are trying to do here

Comment: @DigitalJedi , please check the updated snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `flex-flow: column nowrap;` to your `.container` div will put your `.child` divs below the `<form>` element like so:

Note that they are in the middle of your parent, as your parent centers all it's elements with `align-items: center;`

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  top: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 1900px;
  padding: 0px;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  top: 5px;
  margin: 20px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-color: #3300ff;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  width: 1900px;
  border: 5px solid green;
  border-radius: .5em;
  padding: 5px;
  align-items: center;
}

.child {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form action="getfile2" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <font size="10">
      <pre class="tab"> Import  File:    </pre>
    </font>
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

  <div class="child">
    <div id="slider9" class='slider row1 col1'></div>

    <div class="my_text">
      <center>
        <p>param_1</p>
        <button class="sliderStateChange">Enable</button>
        <button id="turn_off_button9">TURN OFF</button>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div id="slider10" class='slider row6 col2'></div>

    <div class="my_text">
      <center>
        <p>param_2</p>
        <button class="sliderStateChange">Enable</button>
        <button id="turn_off_button10">TURN OFF</button>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    <div id="slider11" class='slider row1 col3'></div>

    <div class="my_text">
      <center>
        <p>param_3</p>
        <button class="sliderStateChange">Enable</button>
        <button id="turn_off_button11">TURN OFF</button>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is nice to see that the form element is on the top, but the problem now is I have the child elements in separate lines/rows, I want to keep these child elements in one line. Is that possible?

Comment: I found it. I used flex-flow: row wrap. Thanks a lot DigitalJedi for your help.